# Linear transformation of a polynomial to a matrix - rank-nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the set of all polynomials in $x$ with real coefficients of degree less than $4$. Let $W$ be the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries. Define the function $\varphi :V\rightarrow W$ by $$\varphi (a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3)=\begin{pmatrix}a_0+a_3&a_1+a_2\\a_2+a_3&a_0+a_1\end{pmatrix}$$I want to show $\varphi$ is a linear transformation, to find the kernel of $\varphi$, the rank of $\varphi$ and a basis for its image.

So far I have managed to show it is a linear map simply by using the definition.

For the kernel, we must have the matrix above as being the zero matrix. This gives $a_0=-a_3, a_1=-a_2, a_2=-a_3, a_0=-a_1$. Equivalently we have $a_1=a_3, a_0=a_2, a_0=-a_1$. So the kernel is the dimension of the set $\{a_0-a_1x+a_0x^2-a_1x^3\}$. I am not sure this is correct though, and even then I don't know what the kernel of this set is.

Now the dimension of the image is the rank, and this is surely $4$ as it is a $2\times 2$ matrix, right? But I am quite confused at this stage

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct idea but a bit off. Notice that if you are given $a_1$ then you can determine $a_2,a_3,a_4$ already using the relations you had above. Thus the kernel is in fact one dimensional, spanned by $1-x+x^2-x^3$ (i.e., the nullity is $\{\lambda (1-x+x^2-x^3):\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and thus the rank should be $3$, using RN.